# External style sheets aren't styling my page

Tags: css, lamp

I have checked using Firebug, and I get the following message:

> Reload the page to get source for:
>   https://*IP ADDRESS*/var/www/css/style.css

There is no reload button in Firebug, and refreshing the page returns the same error.
The address is correct. I changed it to test it and received a 404 error instead of the 
page refresh error. However, I also receive a 404 error if I try to access the address through my browser.

I am hosting this locally on a virtual machine running LAMP on Ubuntu Server and have enabled full permissions (for testing purposes only) without luck.

Note that everything styles fine if I load my local files.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What is your problem getting 404 or not getting the style?

Comment: Possibly both. I have a hunch that the two issues are closely related since the file is in the right place and also 404ed.  I'm guessing that they are both symptoms of a larger issue that I can't pin down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Apache you're going to need to set it up to serve static files if you want to link to a CSS file. There's a bit of info here that might get you started:

http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files

The example configuration setting up a proxy described there looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    # set server name
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName www.appname.com

    # configure static file serving
    DocumentRoot /srv/appname/web
    <Directory /srv/appname/web>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    # rewrite incoming requests
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond /srv/appname/web%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/appname/$1 [proxy,last]
</VirtualHost>
```

This sets the document root for the site to `/srv/appname/web`, allows access from every source and rewrites requests to be served from `http://localhost:8080/appname/`.